# Help Regarding Quran 16:26

Tags: quran, allah, prophets, surah, miracles

Asalamu Alaykum, I have recently come across verse 16:26 in the Quran and I would like to understand the wisdom
behind it.

“Those before them had already plotted, but Allah came at their building from the foundations, so the roof fell upon them from above them, and the punishment came to them from where they did not perceive.”

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain to me Allah’s wisdom in stating that roof fell from above them because I thought that was already implied. Any help with greatly be appreciated. JazakAllah.

Comment: Relevant: [Razi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23635/3444) and [Qurtubi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31702/3821) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever something of the same meaning is repeated, the most important effect is emphasis. The more words you mention, the more attention you bring to something.

Another wisdom in mentioning "from above them" is that it emphasizes that these people were actually under these roofs when they fell. It wasn't like their roofs fell while they were outside and safe.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of their foundation and building was destroyed means that God destroyed them and the idols and the place where they kept idols and their way of thinking in such a way that they themselves were unaware.

**(Example now that paganism, like other religions and thoughts in the world, does not flow like it used to and has been destroyed)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It may refer to the Tower of Babel, as suggested by [Al-Qurtubi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31702/3821)*, see [Genesis 11](https://www.bible.com/de/bible/59/GEN.11.ESV).
I tend to see a hint to the doom of Sodom and Gomorrha, mentionned in [Quran 54:33](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/54:33), referring to the Torah [Genesis 18](https://www.bible.com/bible/59/GEN.18.ESV)-19

I am not so bold to say that I can see Allah's Wisdom ; the take-away for me is that Allah is patient with the sinners to repent but He can also punish immediately. «From above» to me is an allegory to a punishment «from Heaven».

*thanks to the hint of UmH see above